# Django using Updateview for vote Form

Tags: python, django, modelform

I want to replace the DetailView in Djangos [Poll Tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial04/) with a UpdateView. Unfortunately what it is showing is a List of Polls instead of a list of Choices + Votes.

My models Poll, Choices are unchanged. The template for the voting view is kept simplest:

```
<h1>{{ poll }}</h1>
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Vote" />
</form>
```

How can I have the form to show a specific poll and a list of the choices as in the manually build form of the detail view in the tutorial:

```
<form action="{% url 'polls:vote' poll.id %}" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {% for choice in poll.choice_set.all %}
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" />
    <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br />
  {% endfor %}
   <input type="submit" value="Vote" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`ModelChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) and [`RadioSelect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/widgets/#radioselect) widget:

```
class ChoicesForm(forms.Form):
    choice = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Choice.objects.none(),
                                    widget=forms.RadioSelect,
                                    required=True,
                                    empty_label=None)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        poll = kwargs.pop('poll')
        super(ChoicesForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['choice'].queryset = poll.choice_set.all()

form = ChoicesForm(poll=poll)
```

Comment: Isn't it possible with overwriting a ModelForm in forms.py or an UpdateView in views.py directly? In your solution where do I define the form:                                  in the DetailView?

Comment: This is not a `ModelForm`, you have no model to save to.  You can define this form where you want. `forms.py` is a good candidate. You should instantiate the form in the view which will handle the choice.  If you want to go with the Class Based View then I suppose that it will be the `FormView`.

Comment: But I suggest to not use the Class Based Views :-)  Regular functional view will do the job in much more cleaner and simpler way.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but i get this error:

     TypeError at /polls/1/'NoneType' object is not callable

My view:

    `class VoteView(generic.FormView):
        model = Choice`
        poll = Poll.objects.get(pk=1)
        form = ChoicesForm(poll=poll)
        template_name = 'polls/voting_form.html'`

Comment: You do it wrong. If you sure want to use the `FormView` then you have to override the `get_form()` method and instantiate form there.